# Wrath of the Lamb in Revelation 6:16

Tags: revelation

> Revelation 6:16
> They called to the mountains and the rocks, "Fall on us and hide us from the face of him who sits on the throne and from the **wrath of the Lamb**!

I do not have trouble imagining Wrath of the Lion, but Wrath of the Lamb? What's so scary about that?

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons people mis-interpret the ‘end times’ is that they add their reasoning to interpretation. This is especially true of the book of Revelation. And ....many do with this verse.
This verse does not say that it is the wrath of the Lamb. It says that the men of the earth **THOUGHT** it was. They ascribed this to the Lamb.

REV 6:15 *And the kings of the earth, and the great men, and the rich men, and the chief captains, and the mighty men, and every bondman, and every free man, hid themselves in the dens and in the rocks of the mountains;*

16 *And said to the mountains and rocks, Fall on us, and hide us from the face of him that sitteth on the throne, and from the wrath of the Lamb:*

Just like Insurance companies calling catastrophes ‘acts of God’. Just because someone says something, doesn’t make it right. Same happens elsewhere in scripture - example - in the book of Job. Jobs friends ascribed conjecture to Job’s calamities, attributing all sorts of reasons as the cause.

And, just for clarity, it was/is NOT Jesus who brought about this action. The ‘seal’ judgements need to be correctly discerned. (But this is another topic.)

Comment: The verse doesn't actually say that the men of the earth THOUGHT anything or, if they did think it, that they are wrong.

Comment: Who did they attribute these catastrophic events to?

Comment: Are you suggesting that the Lamb opening the 6th seal was not directly responsible for mankind's terror?

Comment: @Mike Borden That is exactly what I ‘suggested’. But ... as I also said, that is another topic.

Comment: Well, the Lamb did open the seals (the only one found worthy to do so) and He is coming *"in flaming fire, inflicting vengeance on those who do not know God and on those who do not obey the gospel of our Lord Jesus."  - 2 Thess 1:7-9*.  Flaming, fiery vengeance sounds pretty wrathful.

Comment: @Mike Borden No disputes over your comments. God wrath will be fully expressed, through Jesus, via the ‘bowl’ judgements. And Jesus does ‘open’ the seals. But correctly understanding the events preceding the bowl judgements will help make full, easy sense of the book. (But, is another topic.)

Comment: "And I watched as the Lamb opened one of the seals..." - Rev. 6:1  Anoigo - literally and figuratively - to open.

Comment: @Mike Borden The following requires far more explanation, but, nevertheless - opening the seals does not necessarily mean that (the opening) causes the ‘effect’, but, it ‘allows’ or ‘initiates’ those events (to ‘happen’.). As I keep saying, this is a separate topic - *understanding that these views are of course just one of many interpretations.* - (but I could point you to a source with a full explanation if you really want.)

Comment: Unless you'd like to say that the Lamb didn't know what He was initiating it is proper to understand the initiation was intended by Him.  It's like a defense saying, "He didn't know a bullet was going to come out of the gun and hit that person."  You have to prove accident or incompetence to make that stick.  You can point me to a source if you'd like.

Comment: @Mike Borden The ‘lamb’ did know the result of ‘unsealing’. So do we! To understand Revelation in a way that makes sense, you need to understand the other 65 books - in a way that makes sense. Understanding that Eschatology has many differing viewpoints, and many worth considering - the one I have adopted is not based on any traditional interpretation. The outline is from a book found on Amazon - “A God of Grace and Mercy - Stoned to Death for Picking up Sticks.”

Answer (score 0):

**Wrath of the Lamb in Revelation 6:16**

Revelation 6:15-17  (NASB)

> 15 Then the kings of the earth and the great men and the [a]commanders
> and the rich and the strong and every slave and free man hid
> themselves in the caves and among the rocks of the mountains; 16 and
> they *said to the mountains and to the rocks, “Fall on us and hide us
> from the ]presence of Him who sits on the throne, and from the wrath
> of the Lamb; 17 for the great day of their wrath has come, and who is
> able to stand?”

When Jesus was being led to his death by the Roman soldiers, he announce to the women of Jerusalem:

Luke 23:29-30  (NET Bible)

> 29 For this is certain: The days are coming when they will say,
> ‘Blessed are the barren, the wombs that never bore children, and the
> breasts that never nursed!’[b] 30 Then they will begin to say to the
> mountains, ‘Fall on us!’ and to the hills, ‘Cover us!’

The destruction of Jerusalem by the Romans in 70 C.E. is well documented, (read Wikipedia below) There was no hiding place then for the Jews who remained in Judaea. Wherever they tried to hide in Jerusalem, or even when they fled to the mountaintop citadel of Masada, they were unable to escape the violent expression of God’s judgment.)

With the opening of the sixth seal, the coming of God's wrath something similar will happen to the present wicked human mankind alienated from God. They will not be able to find a hiding place, they will cry to the rocks and to the mountains to hide them but neither the literal rocks and mountains or the symbolic mountain like political and commercial systems will provide them with any help.

Their terror is well described by Jesus:

Matthew 24:30  (NASB)

> 30 And then the sign of the Son of Man will appear in the sky, and
> then all the tribes of the earth will mourn, and they will see the Son
> of Man coming on the clouds of the sky with power and great glory.

Footnotes: NET Bible.

**Barren:**

Luke 23:29 tn Grk “Blessed are the barren, and the wombs that have not borne, and the breasts that have not nursed!”sn Normally barrenness is a sign of judgment, because birth would be seen as a sign of blessing. The reversal of imagery indicates that something was badly wrong.

**Mountains fall on us,**

Luke 23:30 sn The figure of crying out to the mountains ‘Fall on us!’ (appealing to creation itself to hide them from God’s wrath), means that a time will come when people will feel they are better off dead (Hos 10:8).  Luke 23:30 sn An allusion to Hos 10:8 (cf. Rev 6:16).

From Wikipedia.The siege of Jerusalem.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Jerusalem_(70_CE)#:~:text=The%20siege%20lasted%20for%20about,Temple%2C%20still%20stands%20in%20Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Jerusalem_(70_CE)#:%7E:text=The%20siege%20lasted%20for%20about,Temple%2C%20still%20stands%20in%20Rome)

Josephus claims that 1.1 million people were killed during the siege, of which a majority were Jewish. Josephus attributes this to the celebration of Passover which he uses as rationale for the vast number of people present among the death toll.[23] Armed rebels, as well as the frail citizens, were put to death. All of Jerusalem's remaining citizens became Roman prisoners. After the Romans killed the armed and elder people, 97,000 were still enslaved